# How to setup browser-simulation on an Azure Hosted website

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, browser, hosting

I'd like to check that I have accounted for all my options, before trying to decided which route to take.

I have currently deployed a small website to a free-tier Azure AppService (.NET Core + SQL Server, on the free tiny SQL DB they'll give you)

I want this site to be able to fetch some data behind-the-scenes which requires browser-simulation.

- My browser-simulation is ultimately to scrape some information from the browser screen, and download and save file, but I have to simulate logins and complex navigation, so I believe it needs to be a full browser simulation, not just sending HTTP requests manually, in order to work without huge amounts of reverse-engineering of the target site.
- The site I'm scraping doesn't expect to be scraped, and doesn't have any APIs which I can use instead.

  - For the avoidance of any doubt, the scraping I'm doing is **definitely** not illegal or immoral. It's conceivable that it breaks some Ts&Cs, but I'm already in the process of checking that separately.
- This is a personal project so it's important that I keep it fitting in what can be hosted for free.

I thought this was very simple - I just have to run Selenium in my site.

Alas I have discoverd that AppServices don't support installing Chrome or similar, and that Selenium may not work anyway. ([Citation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks))

---

**What approaches are available to work around this?**
I think that I can:

- Set up my Azure as a VM

  - Gives me full control over the hosting environment.
  - Lots more DevOps effort.
  - I don't see an obvious free-VM option in Azure.
- "Do it in containers".

  - I found a source suggesting that containers would allow browser installs, but keep the low DevOps overhead.
  - I think Azure *does* support Kubernetes for free.
- <s>Re-architect my code so that it doesn't attempt to simulate a browser, just guesses the correct HTTP requests.</s>

  - (I think this is an implausibly large amount of dev work)
- Use some other pure-C# browser simulation. ?CefSharp?

  - I think the current sticking point is that Selenium requires Chrome to exist separately from the C# app that I'm running. If I can make the "browser" be a direct part of the C# maybe that will work better?
  - It looks like `CefSharp` might make it possible to simulate Chromium without having a separate Chrome instance installed, so is that a viable option?
  - May run into the same "unsupported" issues with AppServices.
  - I think this approach probably loses the very pleasant-to-use IWebDriver interface, though :(
- Don't host on Azure.

  - Probably involves some sort of self-hosting whereby I set up my personal computer to host the site and expose that site to the world with appropriate IP mapping, firewall-opening and other DevOps faff.

**Are there other options that I'm not aware of?** (especially ones built into Azure!)

**Are there any other considerations in the options I've listed above?**

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using :

- CefSharp (you can setup user agent to simulate chrome version) (headless mode).
- .NET Core Console application in a docker container (agent) that process requests coming from Azure Service Queue. This will allow you to scale your agents and have more availability. Without VM I don't think you can't simply because of graphic support limitations on serverless.

here is a docker example for this image to download and install .net framework when building:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
ADD . /ScrapingService
WORKDIR /ScrapingService
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x64.exe /vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN C:\vc_redist.x64.exe /quiet /install
ENTRYPOINT ["cmd.exe", "/k", "Scraper.exe"]
```

- Selenium with ChromeDriver.

Test this locally (without headless mode) when everything work build a docker image and deploy it to Azure.

You can do this by creating a containerized .net console application , run it locally then deploy it.
One Warning for your approach , is if the website changes its structure you will have to re-develop your scraping rules, also if the website uses Captcha you can't scrape it, if you send many requests it might trigger an alert on the website as possible attack .